# Something wrong with cycle

Tags: java

```
while (c>5){  
      if (myArray[a][b]>x && myArray[a][b]<y) System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Ieklaujas intervaalaa ");
      else System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Neieklaujas intervaalaa "+x);
if (a>3) b=b+1;
      if (a>3) a=0 ;

              else a=a+1;
      if (b>3) break;

       }
```

I have an array with 4 rows and 4 columns and I cant get the cycle to switch between columns (b always stays at 0) .

Comment: System.out.println certainly does not look like JavaScript.

Comment: Please!  Use curly braces, avoid break, and put if statement blocks on different lines from the conditional.  With those three style guidelines, you probably would have seen your issue immediately.

Comment: With cycle you mean loop?

Comment: I hadn't realized that logic was changed in the formatted code.  I don't have time to reformat the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aray is 4x4 sized your code should throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` hence it will try to access `myArray[4][0]`

You should change to this;

```
if (a == 3) b=b+1;
if (a == 3) a=0 ;
else a=a+1;
if (b>3) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (c > 5) {  
  if (myArray[a][b]>x && myArray[a][b]<y) {
    System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Ieklaujas intervaalaa ");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Neieklaujas intervaalaa "+x);
  }
  if (a>3) {
    b=b+1;
  }
  if (a>3) {
    a=0 ;
  } else {
    a=a+1;
  }
  if (b>3) {
    break;
 }
}
```

Adding the curly braces might have changed the logic of your program, but it really makes it more readable.  Now we can see that it would be better written

```
while (c > 5) {  
  if (myArray[a][b]>x && myArray[a][b]<y) {
    System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Ieklaujas intervaalaa ");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Skaitlis " +a+ ". rindaa " +b+ ". kollonaa Neieklaujas intervaalaa "+x);
  }
  if (a > 3) {
    b = b+1;
    a = 0 ;
  } else {
    a = a+1;
  }
  if (b > 3) {
    break;
 }
}
```

assuming you started `a=0` and `b=0` it is clear that you would visit every element of a 4x4 array.

I highly suggest you rewrite this using two nested a `for` loops.